# How to get distinct values by using c# MongoCursor?

Tags: c#, mongodb, distinct

I use c# mongodb driver to do query. if I use`db.GetCollection.Distinct()` function, then call MongoCursor `collection.FindAs(query)`, I will get a error: `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<applition>' does not contain a definition for 'FindAs' and no extension method 'FindAs' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<application>' could be found.`

Does anyone one know how to call distinct function in case of using mongodb cursor and IMongoQuery? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have accomplished the desired result using runCommand approach.
I have a collection called "capped".  In it are records with field called "x".  I have inserted different values into the collection, among them, multiple values of 27.
The Javascript statement below says "I want distinct values on collection capped where the distinc key is column called 'x', and I am querying for values where x is 27".

In Javascript, it looks like this:

> db.runCommand({ "distinct":"capped", "query" : { "x" : 27 }, "key":"x"
>   });

In C#, it looks somewhat similar:

> ```
>       CommandDocument distinctCmd = new CommandDocument{
>           {"distinct", "capped"},
>           {"query", new BsonDocument("x", 27)},
>           {"key", "x"}            };
>       CommandResult r = database.RunCommand(distinctCmd);
> ```

Comment: Thank you. You use Javascript mongdoDB driver? I think c# is different with that. What I did is override the .eqauls function in my object, and use mongo cursor to process them one by one, kind of slow.

Comment: The C# code piece I had provided in the answer is the actual code I had used in my C# program -- it compiles and runs.  I had tested it.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But the problem is I called IMongoQuery(a combination of several queries) for my mongoDB cursor. CommandDocument does not support this function, and there are hundreds of fields in each document. How to deal with that?